# Mostrar nome de uma fk na grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

Essa é o select da minha proc

```
select f.id
               ,f.nome
               ,f.dataNascimento
               ,f.cpf
               ,f.cidade
               ,c.nome
         from  
            funcionarios f inner join cidade c on f.cidade = c.id
```

e a minha model cidae está assim

```
public class Cidade
    {
        public Cidade()
        {
            Funcionarios = new List<Funcionario>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]         
        public String nome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
    }
```

e a model Funcionario

```
public class Funcionario
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long cpf { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int cidade { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("cidade")]
        public virtual int Cidade { get; set; }
    }
```

Quando eu consumo a service que vai ao banco, pego esse erro

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'cidade' cannot be
>   configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid
>   entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and
>   setter. For collection properties the type must implement
>   ICollection where T is a valid entity type.'

Answer (score 3):

Troque

```
public virtual int Cidade { get; set; }
```

por

```
public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
```

Comment: Linq, o campo Cidade está vindo null no Postman. Como eu faço para trazer o nome da cidade? No banco a proc retorna, mas no mapeamento da entidade eu não sei fazer isso.

Comment: Ah, aí é outra coisa, né... Dá uma debuggada aí, logo vc acha o erro.

Comment: Não o nome da FK, mas me retorna um join do banco e nesse join eu pego o nome da cidade, mas não sei como pegar pelo mapeamento, seja no Postman ou na View

Comment: Ok[.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321479/mostrar-nome-de-uma-fk-na-grid/321480?noredirect=1#comment651293_321480)

Comment: Já resolvi isso. Retorno na Proc